# Limit query with elasticsearch using Yii2

Tags: php, activerecord, elasticsearch, yii2, limit

I'm using elasticsearch with Active Records in Yii2.

```html
    static function getPosts()
    {
        return Post::find()
            ->orderBy('ID desc')
            ->all();
    }
```

The method find () works fine, but if I add the method limit(), it stops working.

```html
    static function getPosts()
    {
        return Post::find()
            ->orderBy('ID desc')
            ->limit(20)
            ->all();
    }
```

How I can use in a query limit with Active Records, Elasticsearch and Yii2?

Regards.

Comment: How you are adding the method `count()`? Please show an example.

Comment: @arogachev Sorry, I was wrong to write. I meant the method limit ()

Comment: What version of Yii2 are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noup.

Active Records is not compatible whit limit() function.

You have to use query() function for this.